# Aptana (Eclipse) will not let me accept license agreement

Tags: eclipse, ide, aptana

I feel like either the **"Next"** button or the **"Finish"** button should be enabled at this point.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Maybe that's only the license agreement for WindowBuilder? What happens if you click on the top line (the `Eclipse Foundation Software User Agreement`)? Does that enable the Next/Finish buttons?

Comment: @CanSpice - I clicked everywhere.  I also screamed and yelled a little.

Comment: Happens sometimes, even with standard Eclipse. Back and forth helps most of the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating to the latest version of Aptana solved this problem.

I updated by selecting the help menu in Aptana, then selecting the "Check for updates" sub-menu:
Help -> Check for updates

Information in the bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=277265

As stated in the comment above and in one of the comments for the bug on eclipse's site, going "back" a few screens, then going forward again solves the problem sometimes as well.

Answer (score 1):

Scroll all columns on the left side to the bottom.

Comment: Oh yeah, I totally did that before posting.